# how to get the number of hours since a certain date in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a function, `getHoursSince()`:

```
def getHoursSince (date):

    prior = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=date)

    priorHour = prior.hour

    hoursSinceDate = ...

    return hoursSinceDate
```

so, I can get a date object, given a constant value, i.e. if `yesterday = 1`, I can call `getHoursSince(yesterday)`. What I don't know how to do is to get the number of hours between `datetime.datetime.now()` and the `priorHour` variable -- any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going about it the wrong way; you just convert the `timedelta()` to hours:

```
def getHoursSince(date):
    return int(datetime.timedelta(days=date).total_seconds() // 3600)
```

which gives:

```
>>> getHoursSince(1)
24
>>> getHoursSince(1.5)
36
>>> getHoursSince(2)
48
>>> getHoursSince(3)
72
```

but you can just as well base that off of simple arithmetic:

```
def getHoursSince(date):
    return int(24 * date)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`timedelta.total_seconds()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) says:

> For interval units other than seconds, use the division form directly
> (e.g. `td / timedelta(microseconds=1)`).

Here's what that would look like in this case:

```
def getHoursSince(date):
    return datetime.timedelta(days=date) // datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```